# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a filter that is applicable for all controllers and actions

```
all(controller:'*', action:'*')
```

If a certain condition is met, I am trying to redirect the user to another page. But I am getting the above stated error. I inserted some logs to see if the filter is being applied or not and I noticed that the

> if(condition){} block was being executed multiple times and hence I believe the error is occurring.

Please let me know how I can overcome this. Thank you.

Comment: you should be returning triue or false upon completion

Comment: after redirect I inserted a "return true". It is still not working

Comment: you shouldn't apply the filters to EVERYTHING. There must be some urls which are not filtered. Otherwise you will end up in a infinite loop and SO

Comment: "There must be some urls which are not filtered" . Please tell me how I can find what those URLs are.

Comment: Take a authentication filter as an example. if `BookController` must be login-protected, you have to apply your filter to this controller, but the login-page itself, say in LoginController, must not be picked by your filter

Answer (score 0):

I have code, I hope this help you

```
  def filters = {
    sessionCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
            if(!(controllerName=="valueSet" && (actionName=="MATReleases" || actionName=="downloadReleases"))) {

                if ("your condition") {
                    def url =new ApplicationTagLib().createLink(controller:'router',action:'sessionExpired')
                    render(status: 500, contentType: 'text/html', text: "<script>var sessionExpired ; window.location.href='${url}';</script>")
                    return false
                }else{
                }
            } else {
                println "else part"
            }
        }
    }
}
```